# Jhipster social login via Google

Tags: authentication, jhipster, google-signin

I added clientID and clientSecret (created in Google Developer console) to application.yml but I couldn't get it working. Any idea what is causing error 400. Error: redirect_uri_mismatch. I got http://127.0.0.1:8080 in Authorized JavaScript origins.

I did everything what is said in Google's tutorial, but no luck:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow#step_1_create_a_client_id_and_client_secret

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify in your Google developers console the different redirect url you authorize. For you, you need to add `http://127.0.0.1:8080` url.

**Little tuto:**

1. Connect to your developer console, click one the main menu

[image]

2. Select **API management**

[image]

3. Go to **Identifiant** and select your application, here *JHipster*

[image]

4. And add your url and save

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another thing that I had to do that wasn't mentioned clearly in the google developer link was to enable the Google+ API.

The various API's are accessible via the Library tab under the Dashboard.